# to/at which is more appropriate here?

Tags: prepositions

Q1. Which sentence is more appropriate here **to or at**?

> 1. I don't want them to come ***to*** my house.
> 2. I don't want them to come ***at*** my house.

The first sentence feels natural to me. But I was wondering if we can use at here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To" is the only correct preposition to use. To "come at" someone or something is an idiom meaning to attack.

Comment: @lea To add to this, if the context is that you're talking about marauding Vikings intent on destroying property, then *at* might indeed be the correct choice. But far more often than not, that would not be the case, and *to* the more appropriate choice.